# Type '{ children: ReactNode; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I do know that there are a few topics here that talks about this error but none of them helped me.

I'm trying to create a reusable Typography component that looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import type { TypographyProps } from './types';

export const variantsMapping = {
  h1: "h1",
  h2: "h2",
  h3: "h3",
  h4: "h4",
  h5: "h5",
  h6: "h6",
  body: "p",
};

const Typography: React.FC<TypographyProps> = ({ children, color, size, variant, ...props }) => {
  const Component = variant ? variantsMapping[variant] : "p";
  return (
    <Component>
      {children}
    </Component>
  )
}

export default Typography;
```

But I'm receiving this error in my `<Component>`:
[image]

How can I fix it? This is my TypographyProps:

```
import React from 'react';
import { variantsMapping } from './Typography';

export type TypographyProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  size?: string;
  color?: string;
  variant?: keyof typeof variantsMapping;
};
```

I have tried changing children to any but i did not work. I have also tried using `PropsWithChildren` from React types but nop.

Where I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare your `variantsMapping` [`as const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to prevent widening it's type to `{ [x: string]: string }`. Then typescript can guess that your `variangMapping[variant] | "p"` is a subset of [`keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L3066):

```ts
import React from 'react'
import type { TypographyProps } from './types';

export const variantsMapping = {
  h1: "h1",
  h2: "h2",
  h3: "h3",
  h4: "h4",
  h5: "h5",
  h6: "h6",
  body: "p",
} as const; // prevents type widening

const Typography: React.FC<TypographyProps> = ({ children, color, size, variant, ...props }) => {
  const Component = variant ? variantsMapping[variant] : "p";
  return (
    <Component>
      {children}
    </Component>
  )
}

export default Typography;
```